# Create Object name with index in Swift

Tags: swift

I am wrigint my first multiplayer game. I receive a list of players of my game from the server as an array and now I want to create an object out of each player with id, name, etc.. the problem: the number of players on the server is random.

How can I create the names of the classes with the index of my array

player01
player02 
player03
.
.
playerxy (xy not sure on compiling time, except for max)

Does this even work on runtime?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array like you said with all your players names such as this one:

```
var playerList = ["Player1", "Player2", "Player3", ..., "PlayerX"]
```

You can loop through the names and create an object in a for loop:

```
for name in playerList {
    // Do something with the playerName
    println(name) // Print "Player1" then "Player2", etc...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, id is not in the array fields! Playerlist Array structure looks like this
{
{id=6346
 name=TheTom
}
{id=5353
 name=BigTestFile
}
}

So I want to create classes named like I mentioned above. Is this possible?

Comment: This does not look like an array but rather like a dictionary. Do you have a dictionary object or is that your server answer ?